# Certain variables from HTML form not getting echoed

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm building a simple tool that will assemble a string based on HTML form input.

However, two variables are not being pulled into the string as expected.

Here is the HTML form:

```
<form action="stringmaker.php" method="post">
<label for="subline">Subject line:</label>
<input type="text" id="subline" name="subline" size="30" /><br /><br />

<label for="emailtype">Email Type</label>
<select name="emailtype">
<option value="advocacy" selected>Advocacy</option>
<option value="fundraising">Fundraising</option>
<option value="newsletter">Newsletter</option>
<option value="event">Event</option>
<option value="cultivation">Cultivation</option>
</select><br /><br />

<label for="campaign">Campaign</label>
<select name="campaign">
<option value="campaign1" selected>Campaign 1</option>
<option value="campaign2" selected>Campaign 2</option>
<option value="campaign3" selected>Campaign 3</option>
<option value="campaign4" selected>Campaign 3</option>
</select>

<h3>Audience Information</h3>
<label for="audiencetype">Audience Type</label>
<select name="audiencetype">
<option value="noaudiencetype" selected>None</option>
<option value="interestgroup">Interest Group</option>
<option value="donors">Donors</option>
<option value="actiontakers">Action-Takers</option>
</select><br /><br />

<label for="geo">Audience Geography</label>
<select name="geo">
<option value="national" selected>National</option>
<option value="state">State</option>
<option value="district">District</option>
<option value="city">City</option>
</select><br /><br />

<label for="statename">State</label>
<select name="statename">
<option value="ak" selected>Alaska</option>
<option value="al">Alabama</option>
<option value="az">Arizona</option>
<option value="dc">Washington, D.C.</option>
</select><br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="Go" name="submit" />
```

And here is the PHP:

```
<?php
$subline = $_POST['subline'];
$emailtype = $_POST['emailtype'];
$campaign = $_POST['campaign'];
$audiencetype = $_POST['audiencetype'];
$geo = $_POST['geo'];
$statename = $_POST['statename'];

echo "<p>Here's your string!<br>";
echo $subline,"|",$emailtype,"|",$campaign,"|",$audiencetype,"|",$geo,"|",$statename;
?>
```

The output is missing the first (`$subline`) and fifth (`$geo`) variables, and I can't figure out what is different with those.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` show us the results

Comment: Try `echo $subline."|".$emailtype."|".$campaign."|".$audiencetype."|".$geo."|".$statename;` dots are to concatenate, not commas. Plus, your question's code is missing a closing `</form>` tag.

Comment: I think @Fred-ii- is correct

Comment: Are you also sure that you have closing tag for form?

Comment: Sorry, @Fred-ii- is incorrect. `echo` allows multiple arguments, and it prints them all.

Comment: @Barmar ah ok. Well, I tested OP's code and replaced them with dots, everything echo'ed correctly.

Comment: Even if that were right, it wouldn't explain why only 2 of the variables are missing.

Comment: Do you see the missing values if you use `View Source`?

Comment: *"I realized that the Campaign form field had a piece of private information."* - Can you elaborate on that and in comments please? If you posted code that you weren't using, actual code is what's needed. Seems to me like you may not have properly saved/uploaded it for the newer version.

Comment: Previously the only `<option>` in the Campaign field was a piece of semi-private information. The only change I made was switching it to generic "Campaign 1" and adding a couple more.

Obviously I know I need to post "actual code," I just made that small change that I didn't think would have any effect on the issue I was asking about.

Comment: _Moving my edit to a comment per @Fred -ii-'s advice:_


Maybe you all have an answer, but I just accidentally fixed it and I'm not sure how.

When I initially pasted in the code, I realized that the Campaign form field had a piece of private information. It also only had one `<option>`. So I changed it and added three additional `<option>`s, but I didn't save and reload the page because I didn't think it would have any effect.

When I added @Dagon's `print_r($_POST)` I saved again and suddenly it worked. Any ideas?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

As it stands, both dots and commas are acceptable, my mistake.
Your form is/was missing `</form>` tag, least from your originally posted code.

Everything echoe'd correctly in my test.

The only thing I can come up with to explain why `$subline` is empty, is that it hasn't been filled. Everything else checks out.

I also noticed that you also have all of these as `selected`

```
<option value="campaign1" selected>Campaign 1</option>
<option value="campaign2" selected>Campaign 2</option>
<option value="campaign3" selected>Campaign 3</option>
<option value="campaign4" selected>Campaign 3</option>
```

Sidenote: You have 2x `Campaign 3`, but that wouldn't affect anything.

There should only be one.

```
<option value="campaign1" selected>Campaign 1</option>
<option value="campaign2">Campaign 2</option>
<option value="campaign3">Campaign 3</option>
<option value="campaign4">Campaign 3</option>
```

(Fixed it to be Campaign 4)

```
<option value="campaign1" selected>Campaign 1</option>
<option value="campaign2">Campaign 2</option>
<option value="campaign3">Campaign 3</option>
<option value="campaign4">Campaign 4</option>
```

One of my test results:

```
Here's your string!
test|fundraising|campaign3|noaudiencetype|district|ak
```

---

<strike>original answer:</strike>

Use dots/periods to concatenate, not commas.

```
echo $subline."|".$emailtype."|".$campaign."|".$audiencetype."|".$geo."|".$statename;
```

Plus, your question's code was missing a closing `</form>` tag.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php). The syntax is `echo $arg1, $arg2, $arg3, ...`

Comment: @Barmar Yes, my mistake. I tested with both commas and dots and it worked. I think it's only the missing `</form>` tag.

Comment: Why would that omit only `subline` and `geo`?

Comment: @Barmar That's what I'm trying to find out. If I can't find the actual problem, I will delete my answer.